# How does Opencart Module saves its settings?

Tags: module, controller, opencart

Hey guys I ran into a bit of a problem with module I am developing for OpenCart v1.5.6.4. This is what I have in Admin section for module settings.

[image]

As you can see I built in extra tabs where I want to give user the ability to specify extra options which will be used to build out a prescription form on the Catalog side.

[image]

Problem is how do I go about Save extra data from each additional tab to a custom table when user click on `Save` button?

Is there a special function that gets called when `Save` button is clicked that I could implement myself?

Comment: I would look at how the core store pages and other admin pages handle that. Seems like the save button saves all data for all tabs.

Comment: It's just a form posting data to the controller. What you do with that data is up to you, and you can separate it how you like. For what you have you would be best looking at something like the information pages controllers

Comment: Hrm, just before posting here I had a look at almost every controller in the ``Admin`` most implement only ``index()`` and ``validation()``. In OpenCart modules are setup to post back to the controller but I see no specific function that handles this POST request. And it seems to only handle data tags with a specific signature ``module_name[module_row][field_name]``. But extra tabs I added do not follow this format as I don't want them to be saved to ``oc_settings`` table.

Comment: All I really wanted was just the name of the function that handles saving part in OpenCart modules by default. I already have the code implemented for it. @JayGilford but your suggestion gave me an idea to modify form action attribute to post to a specific function name. That just might solve my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Eh, I guess I was a bit tired last night to realise that this section of code defined in `index()` handles saving of module setting to the database:

```
if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {
    //save module settings
    $this->model_setting_setting->editSetting('prescripts', $this->request->post);
    //mark of success
    $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');
    //redirect back to module page
    $this->redirect($this->url->link('extension/module', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'));
}
```

So all i need to do is stuff my custom code in here and I am done with Admin controller.